# Breville 800ESXL

Tags: frequency-response

This coffee machine is specified as using 110 or 220 volts but always at 60Hz.
Will it work at 50Hz? I cannot see any issue except for the pressure pump not reaching its maximum speed.

Comment: Contact Breville.

Comment: Unless it has some motor driven pump (not the heater driven bobble pump), it won't care about frequency between 50 and 60 Hz. If it does have a motor, it needs to be of induction type to care. The cheapest motors are universal, and again won't care much about frequency. What's in yours?

Comment: Thank you, I am not sure about the type of motor, but I think the same as you probably it won't matter.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [service manual](https://siber-sonic.com/appliance/etc/800ESXL/800ESXL.pdf), there are 120VAC/60Hz models (Canada and USA) and 230-240VAC/50Hz models (Australia/NZ).

[image]

There may be 50Hz/230VAC models for UK (sold under 'Sage') or elsewhere, but there would be very little demand for 230VAC/60Hz (maybe South Korea), so I doubt there is such a product.

Things like this appliance that use relatively high-power heaters and motors are generally **not** made dual voltage or universal voltage (like modern wholly electronic devices often are) because the cost adder would be excessive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer the issue is I am planning to use a 110 volt 60 Hz with a transformer to drop the 220 to 110 but it will be at 50Hz

Comment: Probably it will work with no issues, since the motor  appears to be a brushed universal type from the schematic.  The capacitive dropper PSU will be a bit more challenged with the lower frequency.